# Why arm cpu can run when meet the error assembly instruction created by ltorg?

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb, cpu-registers

I am learning the arm assembly language, using qemu vexpress-a9 as virtual arm cpu and the GNU as to assemble. This is my code:

```
... @ some vector table code

.section .text
Reset_Handler: @ 0x60010120
    @ldr sp, = SRAM_BASE
    ldr r10, =0x1111111 @ I know it is 0x01111111
    ldr r12, =0x2222222
    ldr r5,  =0x3333333
.ltorg
    ldr r11, =0x4444444
    ldr r11, =0x5555555
stop:
    b stop
```

After assemble, link, objcopy and run in qemu, I got the .bin file and starting at ram address 0x60010120.

```
@ This is the result of gdb command x/20x 0x60010120!!!
0x60010120: 0xe59fa004      0xe59fc004      0xe59f5004      0x01111111
0x60010130: 0x02222222      0x03333333      0xe59fb004      0xe59fb004
0x60010140: 0xeafffffe      0x04444444      0x05555555      0x00000000
```

The data at address from 0x6001012C to 0x60010134 is the numeric that I set in code. I supposed the program would corrupt at 0x6001012C. It is not an instruction but data.

However, the program ended at `stop: b stop` instruction. I stepped from Reset_Handler. The result got from gdb made me confused.

```
(gdb) ni
_Reset () at startup.s:8
8           b Reset_Handler
(gdb) ni
SRAM_BASE () at startup.s:22
22          ldr r10, =0x1111111
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x60010120          0x60010120 <SRAM_BASE>
(gdb) ni
23          ldr r12, =0x2222222
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x60010124          0x60010124 <SRAM_BASE+4>
(gdb) ni
24          ldr r5,  =0x3333333
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x60010128          0x60010128 <SRAM_BASE+8>
(gdb) ni
22          ldr r10, =0x1111111
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x6001012c          0x6001012c <SRAM_BASE+12>
(gdb) ni
23          ldr r12, =0x2222222
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x60010130          0x60010130 <SRAM_BASE+16>
(gdb) ni
24          ldr r5,  =0x3333333
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x60010134          0x60010134 <SRAM_BASE+20>
(gdb) ni
26          ldr r11, =0x4444444
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x60010138          0x60010138 <SRAM_BASE+24>
(gdb) ni
27          ldr r11, =0x5555555
(gdb) i r pc
pc             0x6001013c          0x6001013c <SRAM_BASE+28>
(gdb) ni
stop () at startup.s:29
29          b stop
```

As we can see, ldr instruction befor `.ltorg` execute twice. Why is the data in ram 0x01111111 but the command executed in cpu is `ldr r10, =0x1111111` in line 22? I supposed the program would corrupt at line 22.

Comment: Have you looked at actual disassembly instead of just source-lines?  (e.g. layout asm, or `x /i $pc`).  Your `i r pc` output shows linearly incrementing program-counter, despite showing the same source line twice for those different addresses.

Comment: You are right 0x01111111 is not an instruction and should cause an exception... Maybe there is something different after all at that memory address. Just dump memory from that address an check

Comment: What I input in the question of the memory data is the gdb command `x/20x 0x60010120`  result!

Comment: As a test after first 3 instructions, reset registers with GDB. And 'execute' next 3 instructions, which are memory pool. After that check again `r10`, `r12`, `r5`. That you could validate if `ldr` instructions are really called second time. Maybe there is a bug is that emulator and it's simply `nop`-ing wrong instructions

Comment: @user3124812 You are right. The three ldr instructions do nothing at second called. Maybe there is a qemu's bug. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't 0x01111111 disassemble into `tstne r1,r1,lsl #2`? Or which specific ARM architecture are we talking about here?

Comment: @Michael Maybe the gdb auto disassemble occured some error? It shows three ldr instructions just execute again.

Comment: @Michael How can you know 0x01111111 is `tstne r1,r1,lsl #2`? Is there any way to decode 0x02222222 and 0x3333333? I have used obidump to disassemble, but it knows these code are .word data, so it just shows 0x02222222 and 0x3333333 in the output file.

Comment: 0x02222222 and 0x03333333 should be `eoreq` and `teqeq`. I'm not sure why you're not able to disassemble those with objdump. Maybe try with a plain binary file if that's not what you're already using? Or you can always disassemble by hand. The ARM instruction set references should include tables that show all possible instruction encodings.

Comment: @Michael: I think `0x011111111` is `tsteq`, but bit 12 is `(0)`, i.e. "reserved, must be zero", and we have a 1 there.  So it is UNPREDICTABLE and conceivably qemu could execute it as `nop`.  I don't know why gdb seems to be disassembling them wrong.

Comment: Ah, right, the cond is EQ, not NE. And the shift should be `lsl r1`, not `lsl #2`. But I don't see anything about bit 12 having to be 0. Which ARM architecture are you looking at?

Comment: @Michael: [ARMv7-A Architecture Reference Manual](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f8daeb7f86e16515cdb8c4e?token=), the description of "TST (register-shifted register)", A8.8.243 on page A8-749.   Note the `(0)` in bits 12-15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, you get luck... That just happens that `0x01111111 0x02222222 0x03333333` are valid instructions.

Now let's elaborate. I run following code on ARMv7 (Cortex-A9, SoC Zynq-7000).

```
void test_so() __attribute__((naked));
void test_so()
{
    asm volatile
    (
        "ldr r0, =0x1111111 \n\t"
        "ldr r1, =0x2222222 \n\t"
        "ldr r2, =0x3333333 \n\t"
        ".ltorg             \n\t"
        "add r3, r0, r1     \n\t"
        // crash it
        "mov r3, #0         \n\t"
        "ldr r3, [r3]       \n\t"

        :::"memory", "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3"
    );
}
...

printf("test start.\n");
test_so();
printf("test end.\n");
```

`test_so` disassembly with GNU objdump

```
01a281b4 <test_so()>:
 1a281b4:   e59f0004    ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; 1a281c0 <test_so()+0xc>
 1a281b8:   e59f1004    ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; 1a281c4 <test_so()+0x10>
 1a281bc:   e59f2004    ldr r2, [pc, #4]    ; 1a281c8 <test_so()+0x14>
 1a281c0:   01111111    tsteq   r1, r1, lsl r1
 1a281c4:   02222222    eoreq   r2, r2, #536870914  ; 0x20000002
 1a281c8:   03333333    teqeq   r3, #-872415232 ; 0xcc000000
 1a281cc:   e0803001    add r3, r0, r1
 1a281d0:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0, 0
 1a281d4:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
```

As you could see `objdump` actually shows values in memory pool as instructions.

Result of execution of this code with intentional crash is

```
test start.

...
Type: Data Abort
...
---
r0: 0x1111111
r1: 0x2222222
r2: 0x3333333
r3: 0x0
...
r13(sp): 0x149b8
r14(lr): 0x1a28200
r15(pc): 0x1a281d4  <-- address of Instruction causing a crash
---
```

So CPU executed questioned instructions (which are data in memory pool) and crashed as planned on 
`1a281d4:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]` (null dereferencing, `r3` is zero)

For an extra fun let's make an undefined instruction abort with following code

```
    asm volatile
    (
        "ldr r0, =0x1111111 \n\t"
        "ldr r1, =0x2222222 \n\t"
        "ldr r2, =0x3333333 \n\t"
        ".ltorg             \n\t"
        "add r3, r0, r1     \n\t"
        // crash it
        "udf #1             \n\t"  <-- undefined instruction

        :::"memory", "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3"
    );
```

Disassembly is pretty much same with exception that null dereferencing is replaced with undefined instruction `udf`

```
01a281b4 <test_so()>:
 1a281b4:   e59f0004    ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; 1a281c0 <test_so()+0xc>
 1a281b8:   e59f1004    ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; 1a281c4 <test_so()+0x10>
 1a281bc:   e59f2004    ldr r2, [pc, #4]    ; 1a281c8 <test_so()+0x14>
 1a281c0:   01111111    tsteq   r1, r1, lsl r1
 1a281c4:   02222222    eoreq   r2, r2, #536870914  ; 0x20000002
 1a281c8:   03333333    teqeq   r3, #-872415232 ; 0xcc000000
 1a281cc:   e0803001    add r3, r0, r1
 1a281d0:   e7f000f1    udf #1
```

Running this code would crash like

```
test start.
...
Type: Undefined Instruction Abort
...
---
r0: 0x1111111
r1: 0x2222222
r2: 0x3333333
r3: 0x3333333
...
r13(sp): 0x149b8
r14(lr): 0x1a281fc
r15(pc): 0x1a281d0   <-- address of Instruction causing a crash
---
```

So in this case that's a real instruction abort caused by 
`1a281d0:   e7f000f1    udf #1`

PS: It seems that my first assumption about buggy emulator was wrong after all.

PPS:
`llvm-objdump` is 'less parsy' though, and does not convert memory pool into instructions, which is kinda annoying in this case.

```
test_so():
 1a281b4:   04 00 9f e5     ldr r0, [pc, #4]
 1a281b8:   04 10 9f e5     ldr r1, [pc, #4]
 1a281bc:   04 20 9f e5     ldr r2, [pc, #4]
$d.4:
 1a281c0:   11 11 11 01     .word   0x01111111
 1a281c4:   22 22 22 02     .word   0x02222222
 1a281c8:   33 33 33 03     .word   0x03333333
$a.5:
 1a281cc:   01 30 80 e0     add r3, r0, r1
 1a281d0:   f1 00 f0 e7     udf #1
```

Comment: `objdump` is actually part of GNU Binutils, not the GNU Compiler Collection proper.  Probably best to just say "objdump thinks ..." or "a disassembler shows ...", not "GCC" when you're talking about disassembly.

Comment: I'd tried disassembling a `.o` where I used `.word   0x01111111`, but apparently GNU `as` and `objdump` (and llvm-objdump) use metadata to be able to disassemble that into back into `.word`, not bothering to show it as a valid instruction.  (Like show in your PPS).  I guess it's so common to stash data between functions (rather than to manually encode instructions with `.word`) that ARM toolchains handle it specially.

Comment: `objdump` and `llvm-objdump` *do* support a `--disassemble-all` option.  Normally that just means to disassemble all sections, not just `.text`, but the man page specifically mentions ARM (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html)  - *If the target is an ARM architecture this switch also has the
           effect of forcing the disassembler to decode pieces of data
           found in code sections as if they were instructions.*  I found that in the man page by searching for "data", and yes it makes the `.o` disassemble to real instructions, without having to strip metadata.

Comment: My reading is that it is technically not a valid instruction.  In the encoding of `tsteq r1, r1, lsl r1`, bits 12-15 are marked as `(0)`, i.e. they are reserved and supposed to be 0, but for us bit 12 is 1.  So executing this instruction is UNPREDICTABLE.  Many machines, and maybe qemu too, probably just ignore those bits and execute as `tsteq r1, r1, lsl r1` anyway.  Maybe some disassemblers notice this and disassemble it like data instead, and others don't.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I fixed wording according to your suggestion. I was not accurate in this case. Thanks :)

Comment: @NateEldredge: There must be some metadata, because copying the encoding for a normal assembler-generated instruction (`adds r1, r0`) into `.word 0xe0911000` makes it disassemble as `.word` as well.  (https://godbolt.org/z/a88x4nheK).  With llvm-objdump, there's even a `00000004 <$d>:` "label" in the objdump -d output.  (@ old_timer's answer points out there's a `.inst` pseudo-instruction that's like `.word` but not tagged as being data.)

Answer (score 0):

```
0x60010120: 0xe59fa004 0xe59fc004 0xe59f5004 0x01111111
0x60010130: 0x02222222 0x03333333 0xe59fb004 0xe59fb004
0x60010140: 0xeafffffe 0x04444444 0x05555555 0x00000000
```

That, from your question, is the answer to everything yes? Perhaps this is a GDB question, and not an SO question?

You asked the assembler to insert data mixed within code by placing an ltorg there.  It did what you asked.

Not sure if you understand that none of this is runtime it is all assemble/link time, no magic happens at runtime with the code provided.

As you know from your ARM documentation the condition field for these data items when interpreted as instructions is 0b0000 or EQ, execute if the z flag is set, now we have to assume the state of the z flag is one way or another.

If the zflag is not set then it will simply pass by this data inserted as instructions, and find its way down to the infinite loop.

What happened when you ran this without single stepping?

If you want to see what gnu binutils thinks the instruction is then

```
.word 0x01111111
```

or

```
.inst 0x01111111
```

depending on the version of your tools, assemble, then disassemble.

As pointed out in comments gnu struggles here and did not necessarily get this right (armv4 through armv7 all show this as not a TST, bit 12).  All disassembler output for all targets for all toolchains should be viewed with caution, never assume they are perfectly right.  For variable length instruction sets they are often quite wrong, and too many questions on this site are related to that.  Likewise putting faith in a debugger either in it's disassembly or what happens when you single step.  Likewise an instruction set simulator.

You have piled unknowns and risk on top of each other about as bad as possible in this situation.  So the expectation here is nothing can be gained from this experiment, and certainly the results of any one run be it on a simulation or even on a specific core one of the many that it could possibly run on, also leaves us with no real results as the result are expected or at least possibly can change when you switch form one target to another (one core or sim).

gdb just so happens to see the right number of instructions at the right addresses. possibly because of a combination of layers of tools issues (I have zero use for gdb, as with all debuggers they create more problems than they solve, I find them useless, much more reliable ways to debug are available) it is printing out the wrong disassembly for the instructions, you did not dump registers to see what it was doing.  You did not dump the flags going into the 0x01111111 or any of those data values to see if we expect the simulation to execute or skip these instructions.  Yet it picks up where it should after the first pool of data is executed or at least despite the gdb brokenness it indicates it has kept going. (did it hit an undefined instruction handler for example?). Even if you do these things, what value does it really have?  Was your goal to do a validation test of the qemu core here?  And if so then what results from actual hardware are you trying to get qemu to match, what are the expected results for undefined instructions, etc?

gnu binutils thinks these data values are testeq, eoreq and teqeq against registers and constants so no branches or code flow changes the either execute or not, you can check flags and registers to see if they are doing something.  The first one tsteq if that is even what the sim thinks is the instruction (vs undefined) could change flags changing whether or not the following instructions execute or not.

I had no use for debuggers going in to stackoverflow many years ago, and with all that I have seen since, I definitely have no use for gdb, most of the time I see people use it here it is causing more problems than solutions.  So if this is simple faith in gdb that lead to confusion the answer is do not put faith in gdb, assume it barely works and it is just a tool.  Like using a hammer to put a screw in.

This appears to not be a stackoverflow question but twofold, first a gdb bugzilla site bug report and likewise second a qemu emulator report.

The gdb one can be asked as is, and I would put it at 50/50 that they simply say you intentionally wrote broken code so we are not interested.  Even if you explicitly put the .words in there, I would put it at 50/50 that they do not bother answering.  The real question is why does the tool not match the address and the contents from the binary (gdb seems to be not using objdumps resources and seems to generate worse disassemblies than objdump (from my experience at this site)).

Before going to the qemu folks though you should figure out which sim you are using and look at their instruction decoding to see if they ignore the bits indicated in the comments.  And then the question would be this and this and this ARM ARM indicates this is an undefined instruction yet you treat it as X...That kind of a question I would expect greater than 50% chance of a real response.  Perhaps a we will fix it sometime in the next 10 years kind of thing (I think my gcc and clang bugs take about that long for someone to actually fix).

So good luck with those sites with this question and if you get a positive response before this SO question is closed and/or deleted, then please post the results from those bug reports to SO.